# CSS transform px sized div to 100vw/100vh

Tags: css, transform

I have a div sized in pixels, and centered on screen with the `top`/`left`+`transform` trick. I've created a CSS animation to animate this box to fill the entire screen, but since it's based on `height`/`width`, the framerate is awful.

Here is a demo of what I've achieved. While the framerate is decent enough in the fiddle, in my actual use case with many other elements on the page, the framerate is terrible.

https://jsfiddle.net/ozxyfuje/

I want to convert this to use `transform`, but I'm not sure how to go about it, especially considering the `transform` that's already there to center it.

I tried to use `calc()` to figure out the scale factor from the dimensions of the div and the viewport, but apparently `vw` and `vh` are not compatible with `calc()`.

Ideally I'd like to avoid JavaScript, but I can accept a JavaScript based solution as a last resort.

Comment: try adding transform-style: preserve-3d;

Comment: You can have multiple values, separated by a white space, in the same declaration for `transform` property .

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid script you need to work with viewport units all the way, and then use `scale()`

Do note, to achive better perfomance don't use `transition: all 0.5s`, name which properties to be transitioned, like `transition: transform 0.5s;`

```js
$("#hello").click(function(){
 $("body").toggleClass("boom");
});
```

```css
body {
 background: #222;
 
 /* full screen app */
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#hello {
 background: #b00;
 
 /* pixel size set in stone */
 width: 40vw;
 height: 40vh;
 
 /* center on screen */
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.boom #hello {
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2.5); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <div id="hello">
 
 </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know **it is not possible to achieve it using only CSS while maintaining a fixed width and height** (not dependant on the width/height of the container).

You can achieve it using some JavaScript (jQuery in this case). I am adding the class 'full' to know if the element is full size or not, but you could achieve it with a boolean variable for example.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lmtzkc1/1/)

```js
$("#hello").click(function() {

  if ($("#hello").hasClass('full')) {

    $("#hello")
      .removeClass('full')
      .css({
        "transform": "translate(-50%, -50%)"
      });

  } else {

    $("#hello")
      .addClass('full')
      .css({
        "transform": "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(" + $(window).width() / 200 + ", " + $(window).height() / 160 + ")"
      });// 200 & 160 is the div width & height in pixels, set in the CSS

  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  /* full screen app */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#hello {
  background: #b00;
  /* pixel size set in stone */
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  /* center on screen */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* animation */
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello">
</div>
```